# Secret values are not showing

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, content-security-policy, next.js13, .env

I have a SPA with NextJs that submits a contact form to Google sheet, which works perfectly fine locally and give me a 500 error in production.
on my `.env` file I have as following:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL=
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY=
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID=
```

I do have the actual secret on my `.env.local` file,

and here is my `submit.js` file

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'
require('dotenv-flow').config()

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).send('Only POST requests are allowed!')
  }
// log to see the secret which are visible in local  
  console.log('process.env', process.env)
 console.log(
      'email process with error ',
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
    )
  const body = req.body

  try {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      credentials: {
        client_email: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(
          /\\n/g,
          '\n'
        ),
      },
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
      ],
    })
    const sheets = google.sheets({
      auth,
      version: 'v4',
    })

    const submittedAt = new Date().toUTCString()

    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID,
      range: 'A1:F1',
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      requestBody: {
        values: [
          [
            body.name,
            body.company,
            body.product,
            body.email,
            body.phone,
            submittedAt,
          ],
        ],
      },
    })

   
    return res.status(201).json({
      data: response.data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      'email process with error ',
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
    )
// the log fo r this error is down below
    console.log('error.code', error)
    return res.status(error.code).send({ message: error.message })
  }
}
```

`error.code Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field error.code Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field`

Ps, the secrets are injected with aws and are visible in the cloud watch log.

question1, Do I need to have these secrets in my Dockerfile?
question2, can it be CSP related? ( which hasn't been implemented)

** Update
I tried setting the key in dockerfile which didn't work
also tried to add csp with class component to `_document.js`/ or by adding next config which didnt work as well

** update
On the production/development environment, I can not read the values although its been injected from the vault

Comment: So what is the _actual_ error? The 500 status code is not meant to give any relevant info away. You either need to check the relevant log file to see what _caused_ the error, or do some more debugging inside of your own code (if that is the one that triggers the 500 error at the end there; although then you should already know what `error` contained?)

Comment: I put the error in my question

Comment: And that is coming from where exactly? Is it the `new google.auth.GoogleAuth` call, or the `sheets.spreadsheets.values.append` call?

Comment: its from the new google.auth.GoogleAuth call,  
when I log the email or the keys on handle submit, they are all undefined(empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` should not be used here and after removing them it start working. but still another secret(GTM) which should use the prefix is not loading

**Update and solution**

So it turns out that I need to make a call to `server.js` and request for the `env` variables: the `server.js` is something like this :

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const publicEnv = Object.keys(process.env)
    .filter((key) => key.startsWith('NEXT_PUBLIC'))
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = process.env[key]
      return acc
    }, {})

  res.status(200).json(publicEnv)
}
```